# Suitable control to select fieldnames when importing tables

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm creating a import module for excelsheet for a winforms program (C#).

I was wondering if there is a control (somekind of gridview of listview) that supports a dropdownlist as a columnheader. This for assigning fieldnames to columns at runtime before importing an excel table.

If there is no control for it, does anyone knows some good examples/tutorials for creating a custom control that supports such a task.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to create a custom control, the datagridview supports comboboxes in its cells, you could make the first row all comboboxes and hide the column headers.

Example [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-combobox.htm).